# Adding remeber username and password option on joomla login form?

Tags: forms, joomla, authentication, passwords, reset

I want to save my Username Password of my login in my joomla website.. How can i do this? How can i enable remeber me option for  the Joomla Login Form. Please advice

Comment: My joomla webs has a checkbox for that, just near the Login Form and by default. I Didn't do anything special. What version are you using?

Comment: im using joomla2.5 with Gantry framework @Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

The standard Joomla login form already provides the option to remember your password. It's rather unlikely, but you might be using a template, that has used a template override for the checkbox and thus won't be showing. In your FTP, go to the following directory:

```
root/template/your_template/html/mod_login
```

and see if the html code for the checkbox is in the **default.php** file.
If this directory doesn't exist, then it won't be causing the problem.

Please also specify your Joomla version.

Comment: ah gantry framework. it might very well be what I have suggested then.

Comment: root/template/rt_gantry/html/mod_login/default.php  havin the html code for check box... @Lodder please help me to fix this

Comment: without access to the FTP and Joomla admin panel, it's hard to provide any help

Comment: today i have installed fresh copy of joomla2.5.8 . there on joomla default login module also remeber me fuvntion not working ??? what would be the issue? do i need do additional configurations ?

Comment: Did you install a fresh copy of Joomla with the default Joomla template? If so then the "remember me" option should be there

Comment: ya it is there , but after entering usernam and password  and the click on remember me button and press login button , i wont save the username and password :( .

Comment: hmm that's rather odd. make sure you're PHP and MySQL version meet the requirements

Comment: my PHP version - 5.5.13 and mySql version 5.5.24 and im using WAMP server.

Comment: in addition to that  i have tried that on joomla demo site [link](http://joomla25.cloudaccess.net/)  but there also that function not working (i have logged with username-demo , password-demo)

Comment: hmm In that case I'm not too sure. I have never had this problem and there definitely shouldn't be a problem with a fresh copy of Joomla installed

Comment: on joomla configuration there having "cookie path " and "cookie domain" do i have to fill those two ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that `System - Remember Me` plugin is disabled.
Go to plugin and and check if it's enable or not.Otherwise @Lodder  answer is correct.This is only for frontend not for admin.

[image]

Comment: @Fernandz:Than try Lodder's answer that might be helpful.

Comment: today i have installed fresh copy of joomla2.5.8 . there on joomla default login module also remeber me function not working ??? what would be the issue? do i need do additional configurations ?

Comment: @Fernandz:Where are you looking at admin or front end?

Comment: front end .. remeber me check box is displaying  on front end .. but function doesnot working. when i enter username and passwords and click on check box and then login. after loggut when i tring re-login my username and passwords are not saving